# Alignment in Rotated Text

Tags: vertical-alignment, rotating

Does anyone have a workaround to this problem? I am working on my CV, and want to use some rotated text to improve the presentation. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calligra}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titling}

%Set the format of tables.
\def\colMyBlue{NavyBlue}
\def\colMyGray{Grey}
\def\colMyDarkGray{white!25!black}
\def\colMyCalig{MidnightBlue}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{\colMyBlue}\Large\sc\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc}{\thesubsection}{}{}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, blindtext} %The Lettrine Options.
    \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
    \setlength{\DefaultSlope}{0pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultFindent}{2pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.05}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\scshape}

\newcommand\myHrule{\vspace{1em}{\color{\colMyGray}\hrule}\vspace{1em}}

\title{Resum\'{e}\normalfont{~/~Curriculum Vit\ae}.}
\author{John Smith}
\renewcommand{\today}{25\textsuperscript{th} December 2012}

%-------------------------------------------
%Create the document.
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.075\textwidth}
    %\vspace{-8em} %TOP
    %\vspace{8em}  %BOTTOM
    \begin{turn}{90}
        \calligra\Huge\color{\colMyCalig}\theauthor
    \end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.925\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \Huge\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc\thetitle\\[0.5em]
                \normalsize\color{\colMyDarkGray}\today
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{flushleft}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section*{Summary}
            \lettrine{L}{orem} Ipsum \lipsum[2]
        \columnbreak
        \section*{Personal Details}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\myHrule

\section*{Education}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section*{Employment History}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Which is producing the following output:

[image: Align Middle]

Where I am having trouble is in the alignment of the rotated text, which I would like to either appear like:

[image: Align Top]

Or bottom aligned:

[image: Align Bottom]

The above desired outputs have been achieved via the \vspace{...} command, (in the negative and positive direction respectively). Whilst this does the job, it is fiddly, is there the equivalent to the raggedleft and raggedright, but in the rotated environment, in the rotated sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the optional position specifiers `[tcb]` for `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calligra}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titling}

%Set the format of tables.
\def\colMyBlue{NavyBlue}
\def\colMyGray{Grey}
\def\colMyDarkGray{white!25!black}
\def\colMyCalig{MidnightBlue}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{\colMyBlue}\Large\sc\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc}{\thesubsection}{}{}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, blindtext} %The Lettrine Options.
    \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
    \setlength{\DefaultSlope}{0pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultFindent}{2pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.05}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\scshape}

\newcommand\myHrule{\vspace{1em}{\color{\colMyGray}\hrule}\vspace{1em}}

\title{Resum\'{e}\normalfont{~/~Curriculum Vit\ae}.}
\author{John Smith}
\renewcommand{\today}{25\textsuperscript{th} December 2012}

%-------------------------------------------
%Create the document.
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.075\textwidth}   %% <---------- here
    %\vspace{-8em} %TOP
    %\vspace{8em}  %BOTTOM
    \begin{turn}{90}
        \calligra\Huge\color{\colMyCalig}\theauthor
    \end{turn}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.925\textwidth} %% <------- here
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \Huge\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc\thetitle\\[0.5em]
                \normalsize\color{\colMyDarkGray}\today
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{flushleft}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section*{Summary}
            \lettrine{L}{orem} Ipsum \lipsum[2]
        \columnbreak
        \section*{Personal Details}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\myHrule

\section*{Education}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section*{Employment History}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Align at the top

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calligra}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titling}

%Set the format of tables.
\def\colMyBlue{NavyBlue}
\def\colMyGray{Grey}
\def\colMyDarkGray{white!25!black}
\def\colMyCalig{MidnightBlue}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{\colMyBlue}\Large\sc\bfseries}{\thesection}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc}{\thesubsection}{}{}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx, type1cm, blindtext} %The Lettrine Options.
    \setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
    \setlength{\DefaultSlope}{0pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultFindent}{2pt}
    \setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.05}
    \renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}}
    \renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\color{\colMyDarkGray}\scshape}

\newcommand\myHrule{\vspace{1em}{\color{\colMyGray}\hrule}\vspace{1em}}

\title{Resum\'{e}\normalfont{~/~Curriculum Vit\ae}.}
\author{John Smith}
\renewcommand{\today}{25\textsuperscript{th} December 2012}

%-------------------------------------------
%Create the document.
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.075\textwidth}
    %\vspace{-8em} %TOP
    %\vspace{8em}  %BOTTOM
    \begin{turn}{90}
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\calligra\Huge\color{\colMyCalig}\theauthor} %% replace 0pt by -12pt to lower.
    \end{turn}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.925\textwidth}
%    \begin{flushleft}
%        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\textwidth}
%            \begin{flushleft}
                \Huge\color{\colMyDarkGray}\sc\thetitle\\[0.5em]
                \normalsize\color{\colMyDarkGray}\today
%            \end{flushleft}
%        \end{minipage}
%    \end{flushleft}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section*{Summary}
            \lettrine{L}{orem} Ipsum \lipsum[2]
        \columnbreak
        \section*{Personal Details}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\myHrule

\section*{Education}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section*{Employment History}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, perfect. Thought you might like to know, instead of the -12pt to lower (as you comment suggests, in the updated code) a better result, to position at the bottom, can be achieved by changing the optional position flags to 'b' (in the \minipages) and 'l' (in the \makebox.)

Comment: @ADP: `-12pt` is not for aligning at the bottom. But to align the rotated tex at the top with the title perfectly. Now it is slanted above the title. `:-)`

Comment: aaaaah.... Sankyou Master, I rackie zha urtimate knowredge